# CSS images/background won't start on smartphone?

Tags: android, html, css, media-queries

I have a page in HTML with CSS stylesheet for the body. It works in every browser from my pc (IE, Chrome, Firefox and Opera) but, opening it from my smartphone(Android 4.4.2), background and body images won't load, while other rules works alot.

Here is my @media rules for background:

```
        <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

.headerone {width:900px;
                    height:300px;
                    margin-left:243px;
                    text-align:center;
                    background-color:transparent;
        }

    .thead {font-family:"Traditional Arabic";
        font-size:60px;
        text-align:left;
        color:#A30B0B;
}

.pic {margin-left:10px;
    border-radius:12px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

body {background-image:url("sf1.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
        background-attachment:fixed;

}

.ex {font-family:"Traditional Arabic";
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;

}



.toolbar
    {width:1200px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:16px;
    background-color:#74391F;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    border-radius:12px;
    background-attachment:fixed;

}

.downbarcon, a:link{
                    display:inline-block;
                    text-align:center;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    color:white;
                }

.downbarcon, a:hover, a:visited, a:active{background-color:#B29090;
                                            color:white;
                                            text-decoration:none;

                                        }

a:link {
padding:0px 10px;
word-wrap:normal;
display:inline-block;}

.downbar{
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        }

.downbarcon{
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
            width:260px;
            box-shadow: 8px 4px black;
            background-color:#74391F;
            }

.downbar:hover .downbarcon{
                        display:block;
                        background-color:#74391F;
                        }

#datas{margin-left:300px;
        width:800px;
        text-align:left;
        font-family:"Traditional Arabic";
        font-size:18px;
        background-color:beige;
}   

p {font-family:"Traditional Arabic";
    font-size:18px;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#frie {width:500px;
        margin-left:470px;
        background-color:white;
        border-radius:16px;
        font-family:"Traditional Arabic";
        font-size:18px;
        text-align:center;
    }

.fot{width:200px;
    height:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

.foot, .foot:link{
            text-decoration:none;
            background-color:transparent;
            text-align:left;

}   

.like,  .like:link, .like:hover, .like:active, .like:visited {          
        text-decoration:none;
        background-color:blue;
        color:white;
        font-family:verdana;
        font-size:12px;
        margin-left:10px;
        border-radius:12px;
        border-right:3px solid white;
        border-left:3px solid white;
        border-top:3px solid white;
        border-bottom:3px solid white;
}

.log {
    border-radius:12px;
    background-color:blue;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    }


.footer, .tess {
            width:1200px;
            margin:auto;
            display:block;
            text-align:center;
            font-size:12px;
            background-color:#A5978A;
            color:black;
        }
```

I use the normal html rules for the images, using classes to add display modification, can someone explain me why they won't load images from my smartphone?

Comment: pls post example code to https://jsfiddle.net/ so I can help

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cpmfyuws/1/ here there is the sample code.

Comment: As i see, the problem is not in the tag <img>, just images won't load. Also, images are in the same folder of the document html without source path (as C:/Users/etc///img), so, its only a problem from my smartphone?

Comment: oh, you should use an `accessible image` url and use dynamic link like '/img/imagename.jpg'. The current url `C:/Users/etc///img` is not accessible because it is inside your computer, not your phone.

Comment: HTML files and images are storage from my pc to my smartphone using cloud storage. I don't need to use dynamic link, just put "img.jpg" into the apposite tag. This solution works on my pc but is not displayed in my smartphone without understand why not.

Comment: try to access that image  from your phone, if you can, it will be works fine

Comment: Access work fine from my smartphone, just missing the images from HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Use media query instead. Like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {

}
```

or

to target a specific width between `min-width` and `max-width` of the device

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {

}
```

Use it like this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cpmfyuws/2/